How to Solve the Differential Equation Involving Pauli Matrices and Time-Dependent Terms?
I am trying to solve the following differential equation analytically`:
$$
{\rm i}\,\partial_{t}
\begin{pmatrix}
u^{+}
\\
u^{-}
\end{pmatrix} =
\left[\rule{0pt}{5mm}\,2\alpha
\left(n - vt\right)\sigma^{x} +
2{\rm i}\,\sigma^{y}\,\partial_{n}\,\right] \begin{pmatrix}
u^{+}
\\
u^{-}
\end{pmatrix}
$$
where $\sigma^{x}$ and $\sigma^{y}$ are the Pauli Matrices, $\alpha$ and $v$ are constants, $n$ and $t$ are variables, and $u^{+}$ and
$u^{-}$ are functions of $n$ and $t$.
This equation appears in a paper about Quantum Mechanics, where an analytical solution is provided, but the intermediate steps are not shown. The paper provides solutions for the cases $ v > 2 $ and $ v < 2 $.
I am looking for guidance on how to solve this equation analytically. Any help or insight into solving this type of differential equation would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you !

Given that they do provide solutions in the cases $v>2,v<2$, it would be appropriate to include these in your post for context.

Thank you for your suggestion.

$$i\ \partial _{t}\ u(t,x) \ = \ 2 \ \alpha \ (x\ - \  v\ t)\ \sigma _{1}\ u(t,x)\ + \ 2\ i\ \sigma _{2}\ \partial _{x}\ u(t,x)$$
is a gauge transformed Pauli-Dirac-Athiya operator in the Clifford algebra $\textit {Cl}(2,\mathbb C)$. Background is  the Galilei transform $$x\to x + v\ t, \quad \partial_t \to \partial_t + v \ \partial_x$$
Since for Dirac operators the $\sigma$ operators act a velocities (tangent vectors) and $i\ \partial$ as momentum operators (cotangent vectors), a Galilei transformation yields a crude mix of transformations in all four variables $x,t, p, v, p\cdot v p^2$, that is a bit strange for the Dirac operator  $$p_t + \vec \sigma \cdot\vec  p,$$ that is a Lorentz invariant object with invariance group $\mathit{Sl}(2,\mathbb C)\times \mathit{SO(3,1)}$ for matrix coefficints and space-time vectors.
The solution is easy by the fundamental equation of the Pauli algebra
$$\left(\vec \sigma \cdot \ \vec a\right)^2 = \vec a ^2 $$
$$\left(i\ \sigma_1 \left(\ \partial _{t} - \ 2\ i\ \sigma _{2}\ \partial _{x}\right)\right)^2 \ u(t,x)\ = \ 4 \ \alpha^2 \ (x\ - \  v\ t) ^2\  \ u(t,x)\ $$
$$\left(\ i\ \sigma_1 \ \partial _{t} + \ 2\ \ \sigma _{3}\ \partial _{x}\right)^2 \ u(t,x)\ = \ 4 \ \alpha^2 \ (x\ - \  v\ t) ^2\  \ u(t,x)\ $$
$$\left(-\partial_t^2 + 4 \ \partial_x^2\right) \ u(t,x) \ = \left( 2 \alpha \ (x-v\ t)\right)^2$$
$$\left(-\partial_t + 2 \ \partial_x\right)  \left(-\partial_t - 2 \ \partial_x\right)\ u(t,x) \ = \left( 2 \alpha \ (x-v\ t)\right)^2$$
It follows that the space of solutions of the second order equation is a linear combination of the solutions of the two factors
$$\frac{1}{u(t,x)} \ \left(-\partial_t \pm 2 \ \partial_x \right) \ u(t,x) \ =  2 \alpha \ (x-v\ t) $$
The right side is not a constant, but a separated sum of the variables, so we try a three factor separation ansatz
$$u  \ \ =   a(t) \  b(x) \  c(x\ \pm \ 2  t)$$
$$  \pm \ 2 \frac{ b'(x)}{b(x)} \ - \ \frac{a'(t)}{a(t)}\ = \ 2 \alpha  t v\ + \ 2 \alpha  x$$
with the family of solutions with a free prefactor f of the light coordinates
$$f\left(x\mp 2\ t\right) \ e^{\alpha \left( \pm \ \frac{1}{2}\ \alpha  x^2\ +   t^2 v\right) }$$
Now insert linear combinations of these solutions with four free prefactors into the original equation, yielding a linear system.
The process  can be simplified considerably by the introduction of the light coordinates $$p,q= 2 t \pm x$$

Does the equation
$ \left(i \ \sigma_1 \left(\ \partial _{t} - \ 2\ \sigma _{2}\ \partial _{x}\right)\right)^2 \ u(t,x)\ = \ 4 \ \alpha^2 \ (x\ - \  v\ t) ^2\  \ u(t,x) $
hold true? When
$i \left(\ \partial _{t} - \ 2\ \sigma _{2}\ \partial _{x}\right) \ u(t,x)\ = \ 2 \ \alpha \ (x\ - \  v\ t) \ \sigma _{1} \ u(t,x) $
is given, if we apply the differential operator to the left side again, doesn't it act on not only $u(t,x)$ but also $(x - vt)$ on the right side, producing extra terms?

PDE systems can ony be solved by products of stepwise, reduced length, products $$f_I(x,y,z,\dots)= a_i(x) \sum_{k} b_{ik}(y,z,\dots)$$. Obviously, sorting of variables in such a tensor product tower matters.  n first orders systems  transform into an nth  order equation plus n-1 first order.
An ansatz is a guess for an algebraical simple form.  Here is works, because the left side separates into a product of the independent commuting light coordinate derivatives, so one factor commutes with the right side. Background:   solution of the wave equation $$\partial_z \partial_w f = z f$$.
